# HTML5 multiple image loading

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working in HTML5 and I have two project folders for saving images(one for svg and one for png). When I try to print the canvas it gives me only png image as output but not both together as its a design that is a combination of both the images(png as well as svg).I need some techniques to implement it.
below are the excerpts:

```
     function convertPNG()
    {

var dataUrl1 = canvas.toDataURL();
var ww = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
ww += '<html>'
ww += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
ww += '<body>'
ww += '<img style="margin-bottom:150px;" src="images/products/img1.png">';//I m taking a static image as img1,I also want to implement a dynamic link to render all the images
ww += '<img style="margin-left:-320px;" src="' + dataUrl1 + '" >';
ww += '</body>';
ww += '</html>';


 var printWin = window.open("",'width="100" height="100"');
  printWin.document.write(ww);
printWin.document.close();
window.location = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

Comment: Are you getting error(s) in your console?  A common cause of your results is a cross-domain security error.

Comment: No I m nt getting any error in console.